# How to get the name of the class without instantiating object or having a static method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I hate to see the name of the class used as a string parameter like "FileDownloader" in the code, and I would like to use something like this FileDownloader.Name(), where FileDownloader is name of the class.
Only problem is that I can't find out how to do that without instantiating object or creating a static method...

Is there a way to get a class name in .net without having the object instance and without creating a static method that returns the name of the class?

Comment: I think something wrong in the application if you need this

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure:

```
var name = typeof(FileDownloader).Name;
```

Comment: typeof().Name is refactor friendly, it will change if the class is renamed. Literal strings wont (unless you've got addins for that).

Answer (score 3):

use the typeof operator:

```
typeof ( FileDownloader).Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try typeof(YourClass).name. This should expose the name of your class

Answer (score 0):

In VB.Net:

```
Dim sf As StackFrame = New StackFrame()
Dim mb As MethodBase = sf.GetMethod()
Dim className = mb.DeclaringType.Name
```

There you go. Totally dynamic. Just be careful about refactoring... If you move it to another class, the class name will change... :)